# Scratched Transistor

Tags: transistors, analysis

I have an transistor that is used in mist maker circuit, but it's scratched for not understanding its model or numbers. how can I found out what type is this transistor?
[image]

Comment: Is the transistor broken?

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer has scratched off the identification to make it so that it's not easy to copy or repair his product.

This means you'll have to take the less easy route.

- Trace out the circuit - looks like a 2 layer board so should be straightforward
- Run the circuit while measuring various parameters, with a DMM at least, and preferably with an oscilloscope
- Figure out from the circuit and measurements what parameters the transistor needs to have
- Select any transistor with at least that performance

There may be a simpler solution, and that's to search the heck out of any identification you have on the product, or the board (I can see a serial number or something peeping out from underneath the transistor). You never know, somebody might have already reverse engineered it and published details.

Comment: It could also be that the three-pin device was a factory reject that someone  could only resell after removing the original marking. Makes no difference to your answer – the necessary steps for finding an equivalent device are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It’s usually an NPN BJT with sufficient voltage rating for the circuit and an ft in the 50MHz range because it has to oscillate at 1-2MHz at the thickness mode mechanical resonance of the disk.